# Iterate object in javascript, keeping parents

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object, iteration

I'm fighting with an iterative function. I have this object :

```
var table = {
    "general": {
        "amount": ["mandatory", "isAmount"],
        "order_id": ["mandatory", "isString"]
    },
    "card": {
        "number": ["Regex:/^[0-9]{16}$/", "mandatory"],
        "expiry": {
            "month": ["Regex:/^[0-9]{2}$", "mandatory"],
            "year": ["Regex:/^[0-9]{4}$/", "mandatory"]
        },
        "network": ["List:maestro|visa|mastercard|amex|jcb", "mandatory"],
        "cvv": ["Regex:/^[0-9]{3,4}$/", "mandatory"]
    }
}
```

The goal here is to be able to `console.log` this :

```
general.amount : ["mandatory", "isAmount"]
general.order_id: ["mandatory", "isString"]
card.number: ["Regex:/^[0-9]{16}$/", "mandatory"]
card.expiry.month: ["Regex:/^[0-9]{2}$", "mandatory"]
card.expiry.year: ["Regex:/^[0-9]{4}$/", "mandatory"]
card.network: ["List:maestro|visa|mastercard|amex|jcb", "mandatory"]
card.cvv: ["Regex:/^[0-9]{3,4}$/", "mandatory"]
```

--> Keeping the parents for each field, and show them.

Actually, I've tried a lot of things, here is the beginning :

```
function boucle(object, parent) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var value = object[key];
            if (value.length) {
                console.log(parent + '.' + key);
            } else {
                if (parent) {
                    parent += "."+key;
                } else {
                    parent = key;
                }
                boucle(value, parent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't know where to go. Do I have to change the object ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution :

```
function boucle(obj, parent) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        var parent1 = (parent ? parent + '.' : '') + i;
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (obj[i].length) {
                console.log(parent1);
            } else {
                boucle(obj[i], parent1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this.
$.each(table,function(key1){
                $.each(table[key1],function(key2){
                    if(table[key1][key2] instanceof Array){
                        console.log(key1+'.'+key2+' :'+table[key1][key2][0]+','+table[key1][key2][1]);
                    }else{ 
                        $.each(table[key1][key2],function(key3){
                            console.log(key1+'.'+key2+'.'+key3+ ' :'+table[key1][key2][key3][0]+','+table[key1][key2][key3][1]);
                        })

                    }

                })
            })
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want the function to work even if the depth of the initial object is 4, 5… 100 whatever

Comment: I just gave you idea for this particular problem. You code is right for nth depth. However your problem is solved.